# How to determine correct path to any element of html, to activate script

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have one problem to solve. I have to send event from Google Tag Manager, to application of my employeer, my script works fine, but I have a problem with describing 'path' to my element.
For example, its my script:

```
document.getElementByClassName("name_of_class").setAttribute("onclick", "myapp('event.name_of_event')");
```

Its working fine for example like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-md outline">
                        <a href="http://exampleshop.com/shop/">
                                                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I am just copy-paste name of div class to 'name_of_class' of my script, and its adding my 'oneclik' attribute to  tag, so event is sending to my application.

But in another example, like this:

```
<div clas="quick-access">
            <p class="welcome-msg">Default welcome msg! </p>
        <div class="shop-access">
        <ul class="links">
                    <li class="first">
<a href="http://exampleshop.com/customer/account/" title="My Account">My    Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

pasting of ANY div class, or li/ul class, cannot 'direct' my script to this element (MyAccount URL href in this case).
So my question is, how to determine correct path to any element of html? I was trying methods like:

```
 document.getElementByTagName("a").getAttribute("My Account")
 document.querySelectorAll (a[href=" my_URL "])[0]
```

and there is no dependency, for one element works one method, for another - does not. Is there any 'universal' method, to discribe where in html run my script?
I am not a programmer, it kind of additional task, so thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your browser's development tools to find CSS selectors. I use Chrome, I expect that other browsers have something similar.

Open the developer tools in Chrome. From the toolbar select "Elements". At  the top left of the developer toolbar is an icon with a small arrow. Klick it, then select the element in the page you need a selector for. This will now be highlighted in the developer panel that shows the source code. Right click, select "copy" from the context menu and "selector" from the submenu.

[image]

Instead of doing custom javascript go to your GTM installation, create a new variable of the DOM type, set it to accept a selector and copy the value you have just retrieved to the field for the css selector. E.g.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I will try with this, but could you to suggest me, where should I put now my 
 .onclick=function() { myshop('event.myacount') }   attribute to activate it?